# Can a Oldham coupler and a Anti-Recoil Nut be used at the same time?

Tags: z-axis, lead-screw, z-wobble, anti-recoil, coupler

I'm trying to understand both Oldham couplers and a Anti-Recoil Nuts.

- **Oldham Coupler**: Its function is to connect two shafts and transfer rotation from one to the other while compensating for misalignment. [image: Oldham Coupler]
- **Anti-Recoil Nut**: Its purpose is to eliminate backlash in the lead screw, ensuring precise linear motion. [image: Anti-Recoil Nut]

In case of the Creality Ender 3 V2 both are a replacement for the original nut:

[image: Original Nut]

Why is there no part that utilises both functions in order to have the benefits of both? Better alignment to reduce Z-Wobble using the Oldham Coupler, and less backlash and better motion precision using the Anti Recoil Nut.

To my understanding they cannot be used both at the same time and I could not find a part that seems to combine those functions. Am I missing something? Does one make the other obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't use them together. They are both dealing with eliminating a different effect.

The Oldham deals with the movement in the X-Y plane, the backlash nut with the Z-axis.

The backlash effect is not something to worry about, the Z-axis generally moves just in one direction and the gantry has reasonable mass.

Comment: I think I misunderstand something because don't doesn't each of those options require placement, on both sides, in the same place? I would have to make a custom part that combined both? Such as https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fi-just-installed-some-pom-leadscrew-nuts-and-what-a-v0-wc9uyqipn2e81.jpg%3Fwidth%3D765%26format%3Dpjpg%26auto%3Dwebp%26s%3D94c2105b2b6c3052ba8838e23aa4c38e07d77ecd&rdt=58594 and https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71kOjARIO9L._AC_UF350,350_QL80_.jpg

Comment: No, just on one side, you should check if you have enough space on the lower side as the larger part of the nut is screwed into the bottom parts of the Oldham coupler, and the smaller nut of the anti backlash nut below that. Forget the anti backlash nut and get POM nuts, these are tighter, and have virtually no backlash. I use the POM nuts myself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into POM nuts too. I also need to do more reading on Oldham couplers and how and where to install it, because I feel like I still don't understand it completely. I think they inherently also reduce backlash to my understanding. Some Oldham couplers are even sold as 'anti-backlash'. Making a anti-backlash nut obsolete entirely.